# How does HCl break down amylopectin in starch into amylose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrolysis

I'm currently researching on manufacturing bioplastics. During one of the steps, HCl is added to break down amylopectin into amylose, but I don't understand how exactly this happens. It would really help if figures were included to illustrate.

Comment: I presume you mean hydrochloric acid. Start with the mechanism of acetal hydrolysis. The topic will be covered in any reputable organic chemistry text. As a new user, be aware that you are expected to show some effort to solve the problem.  Welcome to ChemSE.